# swagger-ui: unable to debug source code using chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, swagger, swagger-ui

We upgraded to the latest version of swagger-ui (2.1.2). I am trying to debug the swagger-ui source code for some of the customizations we need to make. The source code is split into multiple js files (because of require.js) and am unable to walk through the source code using chrome developer tools. What are my options here for troubleshooting?